# Check if table within website exists R

Tags: r, xml

For a little project for myself I'm trying to get the results from some races. 
I can access the pages with the results and download the data from the table in page. However, there are only 20 results per page, but luckily the web addresses are built logically so I can create them, and in a loop, access these pages and download the data. However, each category has a different number of racers, and thus can have different number of pages. I want to avoid to manually having to check how many racers there are in each category.

My first thought was to just generate a lot of links, making sure there are enough (based on the total amount of racers) to get all the data.

```
nrs <- rep(seq(1,5,1),2)
sex <- c("M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F") 

links <- NULL

#Loop to create 10 links, 5 for the male age grou 18-24, 5 for women agegroup 18-24. However,
#there are only 3 pages in the male age group with a table.
 for (i in 1:length(nrs) ) {                                                                   
 links[i] = paste("http://www.ironman.com/triathlon/events/americas/ironman/texas/results.aspx?p=",nrs[i],"&race=texas&rd=20160514&sex=",sex[i],"&agegroup=18-24&loc=",sep="")    
}

resultlist <- list() #create empty list to store results

for (i in 1:length(links)) {
results = readHTMLTable(links[i],
                      as.data.frame = TRUE, 
                      which=1,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                      header = TRUE) #get data
resultlist[[i]] <- results #combine results in one big list
}

results = do.call(rbind, resultlist) #combine results into dataframe
```

As you can see in this code readHTMLTable throws an error message as soon as it encounters a page with no table, and then stops.

I thought of two possible solutions.

1) Somehow check all the links if they exist. I tried with url.exists from the RCurl package. But this doesn't work. It returns TRUE for all pages, as the page exists, it just doesn't have a table in it (so for me it would be a false positive). Somehow I would need some code to check if a table in the page exists, but I don't know how to go about that.

2) Suppress the error message from readHTMLTable so the loop continuous, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Any suggestions for these two methods, or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think that method #2 is easier. I [modified your code](https://gist.github.com/strongh/b3ab0d2a00ff25f03b653b7bc46b0c11) with `tryCatch`, one of R's builtin exception handling mechanisms. It works for me.

PS I would recommend using [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) for web scraping like this.

Comment: Thanks! Works well, I had never encountered the tryCatch before, useful function!